How do I run autolisp from commandline in autocad?
This is driving me nuts because I did this successfully once, but can't remember how the heck I did it.
I have a lisp routine that is already loaded. In fact, it's loaded at startup.
All well and good.
Now I want to make it so that I can type a command and have it call that lisp routine.
I thought it was "Command Aliases" in the "Express Tools", but it can't be that for the simple reason that it doesn't list the LISP programs that I have loaded.
Yet, I have another lisp routine that I can activate by typing a command in the command line, so like I said, I did this once successfully already, I just cannot for the life of me figure out how the heck I did it.
I've tried going into CUI to do it, but I can't figure it out.
Please help.

Have you prefixed the AutoLISP function symbol with c: ? i.e. (defun c:YourCommand ( / ... ) ...)
